# Windows 8 Booting But not Showing Login?

Tags: windows-8, laptop, themes, touchscreen, login-screen

So recently, I bought a new laptop with Windows 8. I played around with it for a while and then installed a Mac Skin Pack. I rebooted the laptop and it worked fine, and I used that skin pack for about a week. The Skin Pack included Stardock and several other GUI changing programs, but I could still use Windows 8 just the same.

I then uninstalled it after getting tired of the theme, and after rebooting my laptop, I can no longer reach the login screen. I can see the Windows 8 Loading Screen and it has the Windows 8 Icon and the Loading Dots beneath that, however when it finishes booting up and is supposed to go to the login screen, it doesn't. The screen just turns on and off repeatedly.

It is a touch screen laptop, and when I touch it, I can see the pointer moving to that point but then the screen blinks on and off. I've tried booting it in safe mode, didn't work either.

Comment: No-one here will mail you, that's not how this site works. If you're interested you can check back here regularly for answers to your query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a windows 8 restore/repair cd?
If yes you can get rid of any kind of problem by using restore/repair disk...
You should reboot your system with startup disk, then select repair, everything comes back without losing any data...

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have one. Is there any way to download the .ISO for a repair disk and burn it onto a USB?

Comment: If you have an original Windows 8 product key, you can ask Microsoft Help Desk by email/phone to send you a soft copy of the .ISO file link.

Comment: Problem solved, I restored to a restore point. Unfortunately it was made quite a while ago, but that's fine. Thanks :)